# Safely calling other plugin code from a different plugin

Tags: plugin-development, plugins

I have a Craft Plugin that is a [logging library](https://github.com/JamesMcFall/WatchTower-CraftCMS) I want to use in other plugins I develop, but I don't want it to be a dependancy in these other plugins. Is there a nice, space efficient way in Craft to do something like below? I don't want to have to wrap every call in an if statement:

```
# If WatchTower isn't installed... don't explode please!!!
@craft()->watchTowerDB->log($params)
```

My plugin seems to stop processing and redirect to the current page if it isn't installed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a wrapper log method that's abstracts the check away so you only have to do it once.  The update your code to use the wrapper.

That method could just use `craft()->plugins->getPlugin('pluginHandle')` to see if the target plugin is installed and enabled.  Craft will auto-load the plugin's services, so you don't need to check specifically for them.

Comment: That's a good idea thanks Brad. I could override BasePlugin::log() in these other plugins and have it use WatchTower or gracefully fall back to use BasePlugin::log() if WatchTower isn't installed. That's fine for my use but not ideal if another developer was using it though. I'll think on it some more. Thanks for your time!